# Bash script not running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to learn bash scripting and I'm using Ubuntu Linux. I have written a simple Bash file to count the number of files in current directory. I have written the following script in a file:

```
#! /bin/bash

ls -1 | wc -l
```

And saved the file with the name `countFile`.

But when I am trying to execute the script using `./countFile` it is not executing. It shows the following error:

```
bash: ./countFile: Permission denied
```

The `countFile` is in my home directory so why I haven't the permission. Am I doing something wrong or missing some important thing? Moreover, the `ls -1 | wc -l` command gives me the correct output when I run it from the terminal.
So how can I run the `countFile` script?

Comment: You need permission to *execute* the file. `chmod +x countFile`

Comment: @Biffen Does noone use numbers for permissions anymore ?

Comment: @JID It depends on whether you want to set *all* permissions to something specific or just modify certain ones.

Comment: Why down votes? Some explanation may help to improve my questions for next time. Is it off-topics?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you are giving like this,

```
./countfile
```

You have to make that file as executable using `chmod`.

```
chmod +x countfile
```

Or else you can use the other interpreter like this.

```
sh countfile
```

Comment: Or `chmod +x` so as not to change any of the other permissions.

Answer (score -3):

while executing the file we need a execute permission for that file, 
we can change the permission or
we just run as

```
. countfile
```

hew `.` will represent the current working shell

Comment: *Not* a good way to ‘execute’ a script; it might soil your shell.